# Why Does Portions of My HTML Script Appear Inside the TextArea?

Tags: html, forms

I am practising form design using this tutorial:**[TutsPlus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/bring-your-forms-up-to-date-with-css3-and-html5-validation/)**

For some very strange reasons, these last portions of the HTML appear inside the Textarea element:

```
 </li>
<li>
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</li>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

My full script which I copied from the tutorial is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
</head>
<body>
<form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
<ul>
    <li>
         <h2>Contact Us</h2>
         <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </li>
</ul>
<li>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="website">Website:</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" />
    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" >
</li>
<li>
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</li>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You haven't closed your `<textarea>` element tag so the browser thinks all proceeding markup is textarea content.

```
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: I can't believe I spent hours on this! Grateful, Chris

Answer (score 0):

You also have several `<li>` elements outside of your `<ul>` element.